# Why does returning a type that implements error interface call the Error() method automatically?

Tags: go

Link:
https://play.golang.org/p/z50pUnAe4q

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

I understand that the built in type `error` looks like this,

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

Meaning `MyError` implements `error`.
The `run()` method returns a pointer to `MyError` type.

But the return type of `run()` method in the method signature is of type `error`.

How does the return statement in `run()` automatically call the `Error()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `fmt.Println()` is responsible for calling `Error()` method not `run()`.

Quoting from [docs](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go):

> The fmt package formats an error value by calling its `Error()` string
>   method.
>
> It is the error implementation's responsibility to summarize the
>   context. The error returned by os.Open formats as "open /etc/passwd:
>   permission denied," not just "permission denied." The error returned
>   by our Sqrt is missing information about the invalid argument.

Hence, when you're trying to print `err` inside `main()` its `Error()` method is getting invoked.

Replace it with something else, then you won't see it in output: https://play.golang.org/p/IqScH02iGu

Comment: For the record, this modified version proves that it's the `fmt.Println(err)` statement that calls `.Error()`.  I use `fmt.Printf("%#v")` to inspect the contents of the error structure without actually invoking its `.Error()` method, and I moved the setting of the timestamp to the `.Error()` method itself so you can see it change when `.Error()` is called.  https://play.golang.org/p/3UN98EoiYs

Comment: Specifically, the line that's calling Error() is here (link to master branch HEAD at the time of this comment): https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6f31abd23a6f768c21c8b308f355f3a1bae521d2/src/fmt/print.go#L584